# Работа с массивом в методе .css [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

При наведении на обьект должна меняться рандомная позиция обьекта. А именно рандомно из массива береться один из 4 свойств и к нему прилагаеться число. Но когда попытался запустить(навести на обьект) консоль выдала ошибку Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function. Ошибка ведет к файлу фреймворка. Вариантов нет. Код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var vector;
    var trackM = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];
    var track;
    var color = "red";


//functions
function r_vector() {
    vector = Math.round(Math.random() * (1445 - 1) + 1);
}

function r_track() {
    track = Math.floor(Math.random() * trackM.length);
}

//code
$('#box').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#box').css({"tansition" : "1s"});
    r_vector();
    r_track();
    $('#box').css(vector, trackM[track]);
});
$('#box').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#box').css({"transition" : ".5s"});
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю ошибка в этой функции

```
function r_track() {
    track = Math.floor(Math.random() * trackM.length);
}

  у вас  trackM.length = 4
  например Math.random() выдало 0.6
    Math.floor  округлило  - получилось 1
    1 * 4 - получилось 4
  а такого элемента в массиве trackM нет, ттам есть 0, 1,2,3

  Да и потом - у вас только 2 варианта получается либо 0 либо 4.

  что бы сгенерить случайное число  от 1 до 4,
  попробуйте функцию 


  function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

    getRandomInRange(1, 4)
```

и потом в  $('#box').css(vector, trackM[track]);    пишите  $('#box').css(vector, trackM[track - 1]);   (ну или минус 1 можно раньше отнять,)

Comment: Я сам не совсем уверен как работает эта функция, ибо подсмотрел ее в учебнике по js, но уверен, что она верна. К тому же если проалертить результат с рандом массива стает понятно, что все должно работать. Мне не понятно, почему синтаксис "$('#box').css(vector, trackM[track]);" не пашет. Вообще это редкость, что я не шарюсь в функции, но тут надо быстро это сделать.

Comment: Попробуй сначала потестить $('#box').css(vector, trackM[track]) подставляя числа. Вместо переменной трек. Если пашет, то сделай вывод в консоль этой переменной сразу когда рандомно её   вычисляет, то есть в функции. А вообще 
  Math.random генерит числа от 0 до 1. Так что, что бы она генерила от 0 до 3 надо доп функцию писать. А то, что ошибка в консоли ведёт в jquery ничего не значит.